# <textarea> and MYSQL to display data in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, select

OK so when I try to display data using a MYSQL query and a `<textarea>` it crashed and dose not run.
It works well without text area (but not all the data fits in the text box).

**bellow is the code.**

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_reviews))
        {
            echo "<td>" .$row['username']. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" .$row['title']. "</td>";
            //echo "<td>" .$row['review']. "</td>";
            echo "<td><textarea rows="8" cols="50">" .$row['review']. "</textarea></td>";

            echo ("<td><a href=\"editreview.php?id=$row[id]\">
                <button>Edit Review</button></a></td>");

            echo ("<td><a href=\"delete.php?id=$row[id]\">
                <button>Deleat Review</button></a></td></tr>");
        }
```

I need textarea as there is a review I wish to output that can be quite long.
I have looked at some of the others answers for this problem and non seem to work.

Comment: time to migrate to mysqli

Comment: @Shidil Dinesh I think you may be right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a conflict with double quote. 
Try

```
echo "<td><textarea rows=\"8\" cols=\"50\">" .$row['review']. "</textarea></td>";
```

OR

```
echo '<td><textarea rows="8" cols="50">' .$row['review']. '</textarea></td>';
```

Comment: Thank you I will give it a go and let you know

Comment: Fantastic, it works. is there anyway to make it read only as I can also write in the textarea and I would like not to?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it "not editable" you can use the "readonly" property.

```
<textarea readonly>
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you could use a div with 'overflow-x: scroll'?